# Error while using Exm in Marketing automation

Tags: habitathome

Recently i installed habitat home and enabled the exm by using the custom smtp settings ,exm was working fine , but got an error while creating an automated campaign in marketing automation tab , when i add the email into the work flow , the list of automated exm is empty and an error is thrown stating that ,

```
11400 10:03:04 ERROR [Sitecore Services]: HTTP GETURL http://sitecorehome.com/sitecore/api/exm/campaigns/automated?cultureName=en&sc_site=shell
Exception System.InvalidOperationException: Multiple actions were found that match the request:
```

Get on type Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Server.Controllers.DataSource.EmailCampaignsController
Get on type Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Server.Controllers.DataSource.EmailCampaignsController
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.ActionSelectorCacheItem.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
   at System.Web.Http.ApiController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__15.MoveNext()
11400 10:03:04 ERROR [Sitecore Services]: HTTP GET
URL http://sitecorehome.com/sitecore/api/exm/campaigns/automated?cultureName=en&sc_site=shell

Don`t know why is this coming , i have also checked the vanilla instance the controller action methods are present in the dll .

Comment: Can you show your Marketing Automation plan?  I am assuming it has an "Send Email Campaign" action. If it does, have you selected a message?

Comment: Thanks for asking Pete , but i did that

Comment: did you solve this somehow?